# google-api-nodejs-client - Service Account credentials authentication issues

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to use the `google-api-nodejs` library to manage some resources in the google Campaign Manager API.

I have confirmed that we currently have a project configured, and that this project has the google Campaign Manager API enabled (see screenshot at the bottom).

I have tried several ways of authenticating myself (particularly API keys, OAuth2, and Service account credentials). This question will focus on using a Service Account for authentication purposes.

Now, I have generated a new service account keyfile (see screenshot at the bottom)), and I configured my code as follows, following the `service-account-credentials` section of the [library's repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/#service-account-credentials). I've also extended the auth scope to include the necessary scope according to this endpoint [API docs](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/rest/v3.5/userProfiles/list)

```js
import { assert } from "chai";
import { google } from "googleapis";

it("can query userProfiles using service account keyfile", async () => {
  try {
    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
      keyFile:
        "/full-path-to/credentials-service-account.json",
      scopes: [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfatrafficking",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ddmconversions",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfareporting",
      ],
    });
    const authClient = await auth.getClient();

    // set auth as a global default
    google.options({
      auth: authClient,
    });

    const df = google.dfareporting("v3.5");

    const res = await df.userProfiles.list({});
    console.log("res: ", res);

    assert(true);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("error: ", e);
    assert(false);
  }
});
```

This results in the following error:

```json
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Version v3.5 is no longer supported. Please upgrade to the latest version of the API.",
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "forbidden"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is an interesting error, because v3.5 is the latest version of that API (as of 14 April 2022) (This page shows the deprecation schedule: https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/deprecation. Notice that v3.3 and v3.4 are deprecated, while v3.5 is not.)

In any case, using a different version of the `dfareporting` API still result in error:

```js
// error thrown: "Version v3.5 is no longer supported. Please upgrade to the latest version of the API."
const df = google.dfareporting("v3.5");
// error thrown: "Version v3.4 is no longer supported. Please upgrade to the latest version of the API."
const df = google.dfareporting("v3.4");
// error thrown: 404 "The requested URL <code>/dfareporting/v3.3/userprofiles</code> was not found on this server"
const df = google.dfareporting("v3.3");

// Note 1: There are no other versions available

// Note 2: It is not possible to leave the version blank
const df = google.dfareporting();
// results in typescript error: "An argument for 'version' was not provided."
```

---

I also **tried to query the `floodlightActivities` API, which failed with an authentication error**.

```js
// const res = await df.userProfiles.list({});
const res = await df.floodlightActivities.list({
  profileId: "7474579",
});
```

This, in it's turn, results in the following error:

```json
{
  "code": 401,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "1075 : Failed to authenticate. Google account can not access the user profile/account requested.",
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "authError",
      "location": "Authorization",
      "locationType": "header"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Now, **my question is**:

- am I doing something wrong while trying to authenticate using the service account credentials?
- Or, is it possible that these endpoints do not support service-account-credentials?
- Or, is something else going wrong here?

[image: service account key, as seen in google console]

Comment: [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) is a very useful tool. You can find the underlying service method. IIUC you're using [`dfareporting.googleapis.com/dfareporting/v3.5/userprofiles`](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/rest/v3.5/userProfiles/list). Invoking this method using my user credentials, I receive the same error as you. If you get the same (using your user and service account credentials), then I think that eliminates the Python code as the problem. It's possible the message is a red-herring and it's an auth issue.

Comment: I suggest contacting Google Support if you have it. Alternatively, find a suitable component and file the issue on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)